# LINQ to XML C# get root element attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Lts say i have XElement object doc:

```
<parameters mode="solve">
  <inputs>
    <a>value_a</a>
      ...
       ...
```

how do i get the value of the attribute of the first element (parameters), in other words how do i check which mode is it on.

if i write

```
if ((string)doc.Element("parameters").Attribute("mode").Value == "solve") { mode = 1; }
```

it gives me null object reference error

Comment: Can you add a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: i` mafraid i can`t, the thing is it gives me null object reference error but if i add another element above <parameters it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `doc` is an `XElement`, as you say in your question, then you probably don't need to match it again:

```
if (doc.Attribute("mode").Value.ToString() == "solve") {
    mode = 1;
}
```

If it is an `XDocument`, then you can use its [Root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root.aspx) property to refer to the document element:

```
if (doc.Root.Attribute("mode").Value.ToString() == "solve") {
    mode = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Root`

```
if (doc.Root.Attribute("mode").Value.Equals("solve"))
{
   mode = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `doc.Element("parameters")`, you are trying to look at the elements below the root element (in this case, the elements at the same level as `<inputs>`). You want to do this instead:

```
if (input.Attribute("mode").Value == "solve") { mode = 1; }
```